# How to parse double in scientific format using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, formatting, fortran

I have numbers outputted from a FORTRAN program in the following format:

```
 0.12961924D+01
```

How can I parse this as a double using C#?

I have tried the following without success:

```
// note leading space, FORTRAN pads its output so that positive and negative
// numbers are the same string length
string s = " 0.12961924D+01";
double v1 = Double.Parse(s)
double v2 = Double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float)
```

Comment: I think you'll need to manually change 'D' to 'E' and the leading space to '-', if present.

Comment: The exponential notation you posted is not something that will be recognized by .NET - it uses an `E` where you have a `D`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would first do some manipulation of this string to get it from FORTRAN to .NET formatting:

- Trim any leading space; if the negative sign is there we want it but we don't want spaces.
- Replace "D" with "E".

The below should get you what you need:

```
string s = " 0.12961924D+01";
s = s.Trim().Replace("D", "E");
//s should now look like "0.12961924E01"    
double v2 = Double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float);
```

Comment: I believe the leading space indicates a positive number; in other words, "using the space to indicate negative numbers when needed" means that for negative numbers there would be a `'-'` rather than a space.

Comment: Worked beautifully. I do consider it a limitation of C# that it won't accept the 'D', but your solution works perfectly - thanks Andrew.

Comment: @AndrewS, it is more an oddity of Fortran that doubles use a different (well they don't have to) exponentiation character.

Answer (score 1):

This should help: `s = s.Replace(' ', '-').Replace('D', 'E');`

Comment: The space does not indicate a negative number, it is merely a placeholder for a negative sign if needed...

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone else suggests replacing the space with a minus sign, which seems crazy, I'll offer this somewhat simpler solution:

```
string input = " 0.12961924D+01";
double output = Double.Parse(s.Replace('D', 'E'));
```